# Adding flash message to conditional block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my flash message container.

```
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-autocloseable-success">
      <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
      Some Message Here
</div>
```

Below is my container with a conditional `flash` message. How do i add the above `flash message` to the below container.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, class: name %>      
    <% end -%>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a content_tag here, there's too much going on.   I'd just use some good old fashioned html.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
    <div class="<%= name %>">
      <%= msg %>
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-autocloseable-success">  
        <button type="button" class="close">x</button>
      </div>        
  <% end -%>
  <%= yield %>
</div>
```

I don't know what the yield is for so i just left it in.  Also you didn't say where you wanted to add the message so i'm just guessing.  It's always good to work backwards from the required html in these cases.

Comment: THanks Max, THe message is below the close button... I am just thinking on how this works... where would i pass the classname and message from?